# LookupAccountSid, No mapping between account names and security ID's

Tags: python, winapi, sid

Trying to do a scan over a selected source while getting information of each individual file, (size, time, owner)  The owner of the file is where the code is working on some harddrives but not other harddrives.

The df_path is higher in the code but holds a list of all the paths being tested

```
df_values = []
for path in df_path:
    values = []
    #owner = pwd.getpwuid(os.stat(path).st_uid)
    size = os.stat(path).st_size
    access = os.stat(path).st_atime
    modification = os.stat(path).st_mtime
    created = os.stat(path).st_ctime
    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
    name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, owner_sid)
    owner = name
    values = [path, owner, size, access, modification, created]
    df_values.append(values)
print(df_values)
print(df_values[0])
```

on one root folder it will work perfectly and output will look like

```
['E:/Sams Phone\\DCIM\\Camera\\20180920_224234.jpg', 'Brandon', 3385818, 1576223423.6219194, 1537504954.0, 1576223423.5281403]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but then on others I get back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Python/Projects/filescanner/treeScanner.py", line 53, in <module>
    name, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, owner_sid)
pywintypes.error: (1332, 'LookupAccountSid', 'No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.')
```

Their is no unknown user in the reg or anywhere else that I have been able to find

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If the hard drive came from a different machine then the SID won't correspond to an account on your machine. Similarly if the user has been deleted the SID won't map to anything.

Comment: If `LookupAccountSid` cannot find an account name for the SID, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED`. This can occur if a network time-out prevents the function from finding the name. It also occurs for SIDs that have no corresponding account name, such as a logon SID that identifies a logon session.

Comment: Okay all that makes perfect since, so overall I'll work on making a try block to try it and then just enter a n/a if it cant find anything so the script will work no matter what.  with that being said both JonathanPotter and RitaHan-MSFT would be my solution.

im still new to stack is there a way to mark your comments as the solution to the problem so i can close it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1332, 'LookupAccountSid', 'No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.')
```

If the function [`LookupAccountSid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsida#remarks) cannot find an account name for the `SID`, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED`.

This error can occur at the following situations:

- A network time-out prevents the function from finding the name.
- SIDs that have no corresponding account name, such as a logon SID that identifies a logon session.